# Does WildFly provides a property to read the JMS redelivery/retry count?

Tags: jms, wildfly

I have migrated a legacy EJB 2.x on JBoss 4.x to JPA/EJB3 on WildFly 17.x.
My application depends on JMS redelivery count to carry out certain messaging order.

In JBoss 4.x, I used to query the redelivery count via `JMS_JBOSS_REDELIVERY_COUNT` property from the JMS message.

In WildFly, there is no information on the JMS redelivery count is available.
How does WildFly track the redelivery count and is there a provision to access it via a property or something?

Comment: Please tell me more why you need the redelivery count

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'm good with Justin's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly 17.x uses [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) as the JMS implementation. You can use the standard JMS message header `JMSXDeliveryCount` instead of the implementation-specific `JMS_JBOSS_REDELIVERY_COUNT`. Section 3.5.11 of the JMS 2 specification says this about `JMSXDeliveryCount`:

> When a client receives a message the mandatory JMS-defined message property `JMSXDeliveryCount` will be set to the number of times the message has been delivered. The first time a message is received it will be set to 1, so a value of 2 or more means the message has been redelivered.
>
> If the `JMSRedelivered` message header value is set then the `JMSXDeliveryCount` property must always be 2 or more. See section 3.4.7 “JMSRedelivered” for more information about the `JMSRedelivered` message header,
>
> The purpose of the `JMSXDeliveryCount` property is to allow consuming applications to identify whether a particular message is being repeatedly redelivered and take appropriate action.
>
> The value of the `JMSXDeliveryCount` property is not guaranteed to be exactly correct. The JMS provider is not expected to persist this value to ensure that its value is not lost in the event of a failure.

To be clear, ActiveMQ Artemis *can* persist the delivery count using the following configuration:

```xml
<persist-delivery-count-before-delivery>true</persist-delivery-count-before-delivery>
```

However, this value is `false` by default and using `true` isn't recommended due to the performance penalty it imposes. Read [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html) (scroll down to the "Delivery Count Persistence" section) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the detailed answer. It is very helpful.